# Replacement screw for Yamaha CP300 stage piano

Tags: maintenance

One of the screws that holds the top plastic case of our school's Yamaha CP300 stage piano was lost. It's an M5 threaded machine screw with a Phillips pan head that's approximately 25mm long and a black oxide finish. Two unique features are the captive washer and the cone-shaped point. I replaced the screw with a M5 hex cap screw that I had in my parts stash and that will work just fine, but I'd really like to find an exact replacement (as long as the cost is reasonable).

Searches of sites like McMaster-Carr (or just plain Google) haven't turned anything up so far. Can anyone point me to where I can find an exact replacement?

[image: screw]

Comment: Probably off-topic for in here... but, just ring your nearest Yamaha national distributor, they'll probably just send you one.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, once I posted the question, I was able to locate a PDF of the Yamaha CP300 service manual (previously I had only found the owner's manual).  The screw in question is described in the service manual as "Pan Head Screw（尖り先+PAN）5.0X25 MFZN2B3 PW(W E984200)". Yamaha's parts ordering site https://www.yamaha24x7.com/ will send me some for US$1.87 each (plus shipping).  Seeing as I already have a functional replacement I'm not going to bother ordering any, but I'm glad that I figured out the exact part.